# maven resolve "SNAPSHOT" in artifactory

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I've got a teamcity project that successfully deploys SNAPSHOT artifacts to our artifactory instance.  I can't seem to get maven to pull the artifacts back down.  I can see them in the artifactory with timestamps instead of SNAPSHOT, but I can't seem to get maven to request them using the timestamp.  I don't really know where I should be looking.  I noticed that the teamcity-uploaded artifacts don't have a `maven-metadata.xml` whereas other, manually uploaded artifacts have `maven-metadata.xml` and a `.pom`.  Is this related?

I have tried many times to delete `~/.m2/repository`, so it's not a caching issue.

Here's a snippet from `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://host:port/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
```

I have also tried `libs-snapshot-local` and `<snapshots />`

**EDIT1**: I have tried with `-U`

**EDIT2**: maven says it tried to download `maven-metadata.xml` then `artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT.pom` then `artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar`

**EDIT3**: artifactory trace:

```
Request ID: d888c3d2
Repo Path ID: libs-snapshot:orgPath/artifactId/version-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar
Method Name: GET
User: jayen
Time: 2014-01-08T08:37:30.642+11:00
Thread: http-bio-8180-exec-3311
Steps: 
2014-01-08T08:37:30.642+11:00 Received request
2014-01-08T08:37:30.642+11:00 Request source = 192.168.16.146, Last modified = 01-01-70 09:59:59 EST, If modified since = -1, Thread name = http-bio-8180-exec-3311
2014-01-08T08:37:30.642+11:00 Retrieving info
2014-01-08T08:37:30.642+11:00 Consulting the virtual repo download strategy
2014-01-08T08:37:30.642+11:00 Trying to retrieve resource info from the local storage
2014-01-08T08:37:30.643+11:00 Unable to find resource in libs-snapshot:orgPath/artifactId/version-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar
2014-01-08T08:37:30.643+11:00 Searching for info in aggregated repositories
2014-01-08T08:37:30.643+11:00 Preparing list of aggregated repositories to search in
2014-01-08T08:37:30.643+11:00 Appending the virtual repository 'libs-snapshot'
2014-01-08T08:37:30.643+11:00 Appending the virtual repository 'libs-snapshot'
2014-01-08T08:37:30.643+11:00 Appending the virtual repository 'libs-snapshot'
2014-01-08T08:37:30.644+11:00 Appending collective local repositories
2014-01-08T08:37:30.644+11:00 Appending collective local cache repositories
2014-01-08T08:37:30.644+11:00 Appending collective remote repositories
2014-01-08T08:37:30.644+11:00 Intercepting info request with 'PomInterceptor'
2014-01-08T08:37:30.644+11:00 Intercepting info request with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2014-01-08T08:37:30.644+11:00 Processing request as a snapshot resource (Module info validity = false, Module info identified as integration = false, Path identified as Maven snapshot = true)
2014-01-08T08:37:30.644+11:00 Searching for the resource within libs-snapshot-local
2014-01-08T08:37:30.644+11:00 Resource was found in the local repo 'libs-snapshot-local' = false, Repo is remote and doesn't sync properties = false
2014-01-08T08:37:30.645+11:00 Unable to find resource in libs-snapshot-local:orgPath/artifactId/version-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar
2014-01-08T08:37:30.645+11:00 Searching for the resource within ext-snapshot-local
2014-01-08T08:37:30.645+11:00 Resource was found in the local repo 'ext-snapshot-local' = false, Repo is remote and doesn't sync properties = false
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 Unable to find resource in ext-snapshot-local:orgPath/artifactId/version-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 Searching for the resource within jcenter-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 jcenter-cache doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 Skipping jcenter-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 Searching for the resource within codehaus-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 codehaus-cache doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 Skipping codehaus-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 Searching for the resource within jboss-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 jboss-cache doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 Skipping jboss-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 Searching for the resource within java.net.m2-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.646+11:00 Resource was found in the local repo 'java.net.m2-cache' = false, Repo is remote and doesn't sync properties = false
2014-01-08T08:37:30.647+11:00 Unable to find resource in java.net.m2-cache:orgPath/artifactId/version-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar
2014-01-08T08:37:30.647+11:00 Searching for the resource within java.net.m1-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.647+11:00 Resource was found in the local repo 'java.net.m1-cache' = false, Repo is remote and doesn't sync properties = false
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 Unable to find resource in java.net.m1-cache:orgPath/artifactId/version-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 Searching for the resource within repo1-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 repo1-cache doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 Skipping repo1-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 Searching for the resource within jfrog-libs-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 jfrog-libs-cache doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 Skipping jfrog-libs-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 Searching for the resource within jfrog-plugins-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 jfrog-plugins-cache doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 Skipping jfrog-plugins-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 Searching for the resource within spring-milestone-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 spring-milestone-cache doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 Skipping spring-milestone-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.648+11:00 Searching for the resource within spring-release-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 spring-release-cache doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Skipping spring-release-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Searching for the resource within google-code-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 google-code-cache doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Skipping google-code-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Searching for the resource within gradle-libs-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 gradle-libs-cache doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Skipping gradle-libs-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Searching for the resource within gradle-plugins-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 gradle-plugins-cache doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Skipping gradle-plugins-cache
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Searching for the resource within jcenter
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 jcenter doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Skipping jcenter
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Searching for the resource within codehaus
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 codehaus doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Skipping codehaus
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Searching for the resource within jboss
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 jboss doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Skipping jboss
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Searching for the resource within java.net.m2
2014-01-08T08:37:30.649+11:00 Resource was found in the local repo 'java.net.m2' = false, Repo is remote and doesn't sync properties = true
2014-01-08T08:37:30.651+11:00 Searching for the resource within java.net.m1
2014-01-08T08:37:30.651+11:00 Resource was found in the local repo 'java.net.m1' = false, Repo is remote and doesn't sync properties = true
2014-01-08T08:37:30.653+11:00 Searching for the resource within repo1
2014-01-08T08:37:30.653+11:00 repo1 doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.653+11:00 Skipping repo1
2014-01-08T08:37:30.653+11:00 Searching for the resource within jfrog-libs
2014-01-08T08:37:30.653+11:00 jfrog-libs doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.653+11:00 Skipping jfrog-libs
2014-01-08T08:37:30.653+11:00 Searching for the resource within jfrog-plugins
2014-01-08T08:37:30.653+11:00 jfrog-plugins doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.653+11:00 Skipping jfrog-plugins
2014-01-08T08:37:30.653+11:00 Searching for the resource within spring-milestone
2014-01-08T08:37:30.654+11:00 spring-milestone doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.654+11:00 Skipping spring-milestone
2014-01-08T08:37:30.654+11:00 Searching for the resource within spring-release
2014-01-08T08:37:30.654+11:00 spring-release doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Skipping spring-release
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Searching for the resource within google-code
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 google-code doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Skipping google-code
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Searching for the resource within gradle-libs
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 gradle-libs doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Skipping gradle-libs
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Searching for the resource within gradle-plugins
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 gradle-plugins doesn't handle snapshot resources
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Skipping gradle-plugins
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Returning an unfound resource
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Requested resource is found = false
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Request is HEAD = false
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Request is for a checksum = false
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Target repository is not remote or doesn't store locally = true
2014-01-08T08:37:30.655+11:00 Requested resource was not modified = false
2014-01-08T08:37:30.656+11:00 Responding with unfound resource
2014-01-08T08:37:30.656+11:00 Setting default response status to '404' reason to 'Resource not found'
2014-01-08T08:37:30.656+11:00 Response is an instance of UnfoundRepoResourceReason
2014-01-08T08:37:30.656+11:00 Configured to hide un-authorized resources = false
2014-01-08T08:37:30.656+11:00 Original response status is auth related = false
2014-01-08T08:37:30.656+11:00 Using original response status of '404' and message 'Artifact not found: orgPath/artifactId/version-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar'
2014-01-08T08:37:30.656+11:00 Sending error with status 404 and message 'Artifact not found: orgPath/artifactId/version-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar'
2014-01-08T08:37:30.657+11:00 Executing any AfterDownloadErrorAction user plugins that may exist
2014-01-08T08:37:30.657+11:00 Response code wasn't modified by the user plugins
2014-01-08T08:37:30.657+11:00 Sending response with the status '404' and the message 'Artifact not found: orgPath/artifactId/version-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar'
2014-01-08T08:37:30.657+11:00 Request failed with no exception
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `-U` (or `--update-snapshots`) flag, which   forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote
repositories, when executing maven?

Comment: Try to run the trace command on your artifact (the path to it with `-SNAPSHOT` version, followed by `?trace`) and append the results to the question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Artifactory Teamcity plugin needs to be told to upload the `.pom` with the `.jar`.

Comment: In the Artifactory plugin for Jenkins, I had to set the "Deploy maven artifacts" -> "Include Patterns" to `**/*jar, **/*pom`.  I had the POM portion missing and this answer helped me figure that out.